# Jest / JSDOM - Pages of red output in test window when assigning to document

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, jsdom

This is my test.  When the comparison function fails, I will add a class to the input box, hence my test expects the classList to be of length 2.

```
     describe('confirm password element', () => {
        it('adds a class to the input box when the text fails comparison check', () => {
        document.body.innerHTML =
        ' <form>' +
        '<input class="confirm-password">' + 
        ' </form>';
          const e = document.querySelector('.confirm-password').classList;
          // keypress event to trigger comparison function will be here.
          expect(e).toHaveLength(2);
        })
     })
```

However, as soon as I run my tests, i get pages and pages of output in the test terminal  window, a snippet of which is below..

```
ect]}, Symbol(wrapper): {Symbol(impl): [Circular]}, Symbol(location info): {"end": 32, "endTag": [Object], "start": 19, "startTag": [Object]}}, "previousSibling": null}, Symbol(wrapper): {Symbol(impl): [Circular]}, Symbol(location info): undefined}}, Symbol(wrapper): {Symbol(impl): [Circular]}, Symbol(location info): undefined}, "previousSibling": null}, Symbol(wrapper): {Symbol(impl): [Circular]}, Symbol(location info): undefined}, "tokens": ["confirm-password"]}}
```

When I comment out the second last line beginning with 'const e', this stops the text output. Incidentally, the test evaluates correctly despite all this unwanted output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the test with `--verbose`? The snippet doesn’t look like an error. It could just be very chatty logging.